# What is the difference between importing .scss file in <script> tag and <style> tag in SvelteKit?

Tags: css, sass, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm new to SvelteKit and Vite and I'm trying to understand what is the difference between importing a `.scss` file inside the *script* tag and *style* tag.

```
<script>
    import 'app.scss'
</script>
```

VS.

```
<style>
  @import "app.scss";
</style>
```

From my understanding this is something specific to Vite which is enabled in SvelteKit
by utilising `vite-plugin-svelte` plugin which exports [vitePreprocess](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/preprocess.md).

1. What is the difference between the two styles of imports? Are they processed differently?
2. Why am I allowed to import `.scss` files inside the *script* tag? Shouldn't it throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

1. There should not be any difference here<sup>1</sup>. Vite by default [processes `@import`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#import-inlining-and-rebasing) so you do not get a requests cascade (request to stylesheet containing `@import`, request to file referenced, etc.).
2. Build tools like Vite allow all kinds of imports, they are processed to something else depending on what is being imported (e.g. image assets are [imported as URLs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url)). CSS imports add the styles to the component's CSS.

---

<sup>1</sup>Depending on the processor being used there can be differences, e.g. there is [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess), which is a bit more advanced, where imports in the style can be scoped, so you would need to add [`:global`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess#global-rule):

```html
<style lang="scss">
  .scoped-style {
  }

  :global {
    @import 'global-stylesheet.scss';

    .global-style {
      .global-child-style {
      }
    }
  }
</style>
```